# Is it harmful to turn off your laptop directly from the power button?

Tags: hard-drive

In case my system hangs, is it harmful to directly turn off the laptop by holding the power button since I do not have another choice. Does it cause any serious hardware dent?

Comment: Why don’t you have another choice?

Comment: There is no other choice because the machine is unresponsive to all other input.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible damage is, if the system doesn't use a file-system that can handle such cases, that the disk might be in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Would it be a correct assumption that all modern filesystems can handle this? NTFS, EXT4, etc?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that. But yes, they should, although some like NTFS are not as reliable.

Comment: I used to just shutdown my Windows PC by holding the power button (feels like putting a pillow over the PC's head, hehe), as this was much faster than waiting for it to shutdown. But it can corrupt the disk (NTFS), which happened to me once. So I wouldn't recommend doing it too often.